# IE version script comment blocks are not formatted by the code styler

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-formatting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036534/ie8-attr-is-null-or-not-an-object) deals with [IE specific code blocks that work off special html comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Is there any way that the code formatted could recognize these special format codes and still comment the javascript (and html) inside?

Answer (score 4):

We can force certain language upon a code block by adding such a line above the code:

```
<!-- language: lang-[language here] -->
```

After quick trial and error, this one did the trick:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

More details can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: And more details at (the links at) [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Yep, should have linked to that before! :)

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that conditional comments should be handled by the default syntax highlighter. For one thing, they are an ancient relic, and even IE is discontinuing support for it – as the page you linked to says:

> **Important**  As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode

Fun fact: Until 2012 (!), that page contained the following text instead:

> Conditional comments make it easy for developers to take advantage of the enhanced features offered by Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 and later versions, while writing pages that downgrade gracefully in less-capable browsers or display correctly in browsers other than Windows Internet Explorer.

More importantly however, a conditional comment is just that – a comment. So in the context of HTML, it is correct for the syntax highlighter to highlight it as such.